# How to move pin and drop when drag map then release

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I want to implement functionality like when i move the map the pin also moves and drop where i want to and become from current location of user.

I have tried below code:

```
- (nullable MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {  
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {  
        return nil;    
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear what you want?

Comment: please explain your problem.

Comment: i want  ....when i move the map my current location pin also moves and drop where i want to .And become from current to pick up location....any help would be thankful

Answer (score 2):

This code is in Swifty, but analogous in Obj-C.
Add a gesture recognizer to the mapView:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapViewTapped))
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Then, when you get a touch on the map, convert it to a relative point on the mapView and then query the map location:

```
func mapViewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let coordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
    addPin(at: coordinate)
}
```

Finally, add the pin to the map:

```
func addPin(at coordiante: Coordinate) {
    let newAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    newAnnotation.coordinate = coordiante

    mapView.addAnnotation(newAnnotation)
}
```